# Mockito not mocking SharedPreferences

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I have a problem with Mockito. I have written tests for my presentation layer. I used mockito to mock some dependencies. Everything was working fin for last 2 months and suddenly I started receiving an exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Landroid/content/SharedPreferences;

Previously there were no problem with it at all. I have not changed the version of Mockito and JUnit in my gradle and it looks like:

> ```
> testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"
> testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
> ```

And my test class looks like:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) 
public class PostDetailsPresenterTest {
    @Mock
     SharedPreferences preferences;

     @Before
     public void setUp() {
         SharedPrefsUtils utils = new SharedPrefsUtils(preferences);
     } 
}
```

But after starting tests I keep receiving an exception. Does someone had similar problem and know how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean and rebuild. Then `./gradlew clean test`. If that doesn't help, remove the `.gradle` folder from your project and rebuild.